# display downloaded layouts in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-xml

I want to make an application that has a fixed background image and using a ViewPager allows the user to swipe different layouts (with text and images) that overlay the fixed background.

I want to insert few fixed layouts in the app, and allows the user to download from internet others overlaying layouts.
Can I load xml layouts from a local drive and programmatically insert them? Or is it better download some json files, and build a brand new layout from this information?

Comment: you could certainly download some json files that contain all the information and make a method to interpret it and just create the layouts programatically. here's a nice tutorial: http://startandroid.ru/en/lessons/complete-list/220-lesson-16-creating-layout-programmatically-layoutparams.html

Comment: Can I download an xml layout file, saving the xml file locally and after inflate this xml in the current layout?